# How to perform 'Handsontable' automation using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, handsontable

I have a handsontable with locator as:

```
.//*[@class='ui-handsontable-container handsontable']/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

The html of the handsontable appears like this before any data in it:

```
<td class="currentCol fill" title="undefined">
```

If i manually type "Test" in the first row of the table from front end,then html change will appear like this:

```
<td class="currentCol fill" title="Test">Test</td
```

i.e 'title' attribute get sets to the value "Test" but if i do the same with automation using jsexecuter as:

```
public String setAttribute(String locator, String value) {
    try {
        w = findElement(locator);


        if (w != null) {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('title','"+ value +"')",w);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("EXCEPTION: In setAttribute: "+locator);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It will set "Test" value to title attribute but won't  that value come in the table i.e  html will appear like this only:

```
<td class="currentCol fill" title="Test">
```

Please suggest how it can be tackled?

Comment: please put more of your intentiosn in the question and specify what you exactly need and tried so far!

Comment: I have locator of handsontable as .//*[@class='ui-handsontable-container handsontable']/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td" but i am not able to write into it.

Comment: I have tried by setting attribute also but it won't work :                                              public String setAttribute(String locator, String value) {
  try {
   w = findElement(locator);
   
   
   if (w != null) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('title','"+ value +"')",w);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   logger.error("EXCEPTION: In setAttribute: "+locator);
  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: Put this well formated into your question and explain a little bit more of your intensions and than you have a well formated question and getting maby an answer.

Comment: yup.done.Now if u suggest some soln if u can.